# Single Responsibility Principle

Tags: c#, .net

Según SOLID, Single Responsibility Principle dice, Es de única responsabilidad y dice que cada clase debe ocuparse de un solo menester y eso aplica para sus métodos.
Yo tengo un método Guardar el cual actualiza un registro y también guarda un registro, tiene dos responsabilidades.

```
if (HelpAccesoDatos.Existe)) {
   try {
      ClienteRepository.Actualizar(cliente);
      MensajeLogica = "REGISTRO ACTUALIZADO!!!";
   } catch (Exception) {
      MensajeError = "No se puedo actualizar el registro";
   }
} else {
   try {
      ClienteRepository.Guardar(cliente);
      MensajeLogica = "REGISTRO GUARDADO!!!";
   } catch (Exception) {
      MensajeError = "No se pudo guardar el registro";
   }
}
```

¿Debería separar este método en dos?, ¿es una mala práctica de programación?, de mi punto de vista me siento cómodo con este método tanto para mantenimientos de código e implementación. Les agradezco de antemano sus recomendaciones.

Comment: Depende de como lo veas, también podría ser que su única responsabilidad es escribir datos.

Comment: Pregunta muy parecida a [*Learning Single Responsibility Principle with C#*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542051/learning-single-responsibility-principle-with-c-sharp) (en *inglés*).

Comment: Me parece que to aun sigue SOLID asi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**>>¿Debería separar este método en dos?**

No hace falta separar la funcionalidad en este caso ya que si bien defines logica para dos posibles caminos estas hacen referencia a un solo tipo de operacion, la de persistir datos.

Esa practica SOLID se refiere a casos en donde la entidad ademas de guardar la entidad por ejemplo envia un mail, o quizas ademas de persistir se conecta a un servicio web para realizar otra operacion, alli si estarias violando claramente el principio SOLID que mencionas.

O tambien si en la funcionalidad de la clase defines persistencia para muchos tipos de entidades diferentes.

En tu caso a lo sumo estas validando para realizar un INSERT o UPDATE, pero se trata de la misma entidad y de una operacion simple de persistencia.

[SRP – Principio de responsabilidad simple](https://sebys.com.ar/2010/05/25/srp-principio-de-responsabilidad-simple/)

[S.O.L.I.D Principio de Responsabilidad Simple](http://eljaviador.com/SOLID-principio-de-responsabilidad-simple.html)

Comment: Leandro, gracias por la explicación.

Comment: Leandro aprovechando este tema y del método expuesto en este hilo, que se puede hacer para evitar menos idas y vueltas al gestor de base de datos, por que si voy a actualizar y se que existe un registro ya para que preguntar si existe y si voy a guardar ya se que no existe.

Comment: podrias no ir contra la db si es que en la entidad tienes un id asignado a la entidad, o sea si la entidad tiene un id igual a cero entonces insertas, pero si es uno diferente actualizas, de esta forma no necesitas validar si existe, pero por supuesto si actualizas y el id no existe deberas controlar el fallo